# what function boolean in while in this code

Tags: java

I don't understand what boolean function in my code.Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

class Example {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        String s="";
        boolean read=false;         
        int x;

        System.out.println("Enter your name:");

        try{


            while(!read){
                x=System.in.read();

                if(x < -1 || x == '\n')
                    read=true;
                s=s + (char)x;


            }

        }catch(IOException io){
            System.err.println(io.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println(s);

    }
}
```

why if i change variable boolean read value to true.While statement seems infinite loop.Can somebody explain why?

Comment: you should use a Scanner object

Comment: If `System.in.read()` fails or returns a newline, should you add that failure value or newline to the string `s`? You do that now.

Comment: If I print the x variable.The result is int but his fine.But, when I change the read variable value to true.The input stream won't read.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting an infinite loop?  It seems to me that if you changed the second line of `main` to `boolean read = true;` then your program would exit quickly, without any visible output.  Maybe that's what's happening to you.

Comment: Just as a matter of clarity, perhaps you should not use the variable name 'read' for your boolean while you are also using the read() method.. it could become confusing

Comment: Perhaps you should learn how to use a *debugger*. With a debugger you can step through the code, line by line, while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: And if change both of boolean value same.It seem not work.

Answer (score 1):

Here read is a boolean variable not a function. Just like you have int, String, boolean is a data type that has only two values true or false. Initially you assign read as false. So the while loop atleast executes once.

```
while(!read)
```

The above statement is shortened and can be rewritten as follows

```
while(read ==false)
```

Both are the same.
The program keeps reading the characters unless you input a number < -1 or presses enter (new line denoted by \n), then you assign read as true and the while loop stops executing as the above condition is not true.

Answer (score 0):

The [`System.in.read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) function return `-1` on end-of-file (or end-of-input). That means your comparison `x < -1` will *never* be true.

You should check for *equality* with `-1` instead: `x == -1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation